# How to do a group by clause with a max

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that looks like thos :

```
SELECT max(insert_date),
       creative_id,
       creative_object
FROM   rtb_creatives
WHERE  adgroup_id = 'agid1608844879'
       AND is_delete IN ( 0 )
GROUP  BY insert_date,
          creative_id,
          creative_object
```

E.g.  I have 4 rows:
insert_date creative_id, creative_object

```
 june 12 a b
 june13 a b
 june 12 c d
 june13 c d
```

The query is returning all rows.

I need to return

```
june13 a b
 june13 c d
```

How do I modify the query?

Comment: would it be `group by MAX(insert_date)`?

Comment: remove insert_date from group by and try again and tell us what is happening .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `insert_date` from the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT max(insert_date) AS insert_date, creative_id, creative_object
from rtb_creatives 
where adgroup_id='agid1608844879' and is_delete in (0)
group by creative_id, creative_object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table rtb_creatives (insert_date varchar(20), creative_id char(1), creative_object char(1));
insert into rtb_creatives (insert_date, creative_id, creative_object) values
('june 12', 'a', 'b'),
('june 13', 'a', 'b'),
('june 12', 'c', 'd'),
('june 13', 'c', 'd')
;

SELECT insert_date, creative_id, creative_object 
from rtb_creatives 
where 
    adgroup_id='agid1608844879' 
    and is_delete in (0)
    and insert_date = (select max(insert_date) from rtb_creatives)
group by insert_date, creative_id, creative_object
;
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
| insert_date | creative_id | creative_object |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
| june 13     | a           | b               |
| june 13     | c           | d               |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know, what the maximum date for particular `creative_id` and `creative_object` is, you just need to remove insert_date from `GROUP BY` clause, witch will cause to select maximum date for every group, also I would change the IN condition to make it more clear (although in this particular case it does not make a big difference), like that:

```
SELECT max(insert_date) as insert_date,
       creative_id,
       creative_object
FROM   rtb_creatives
WHERE  adgroup_id = 'agid1608844879'
       AND is_delete =  0
GROUP  BY creative_id,
          creative_object
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in here is that your insert date is defined as a string. It should be defined as a date type so that Max() may calculate the right order. Assume that there is an other date such as August 05 as insert date then Max would return June 13. And keep in mind that in string ordering there is a difference in June13 and June 13.

When you max(an expression) the expression should not be in the group by clause.

`GROUP  BY insert_date,
    creative_id,
          creative_object`

Hope this helps.